# jqmobi. on ios (ipod) when input field focused content moves up

Tags: css, ios, html, cordova, jqmobi

I'm using jqmobi.
http://jqmobi.com/testdrive - same here

On iOS when the input field becomes focused, the content moves up. I want the header to stay in the same position.

Comment: As far as I know you can't control how the page moves when you focus on an input area in iOS. It's defined by the browser and not by the page or code.

Comment: As Blieque said, you can not control that.  The browser decides what to do - test any other framework and it happens with all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no method to do it in the current jqMobi version.
A Workaround is to reposition #jQUi style.top according to the document.body.scrollTop when the phone enters keyboard mode;

You can use $.touchLayer event 'enter-edit-reshape' and 'exit-edit-reshape' to detect the resize cross-browser.

```
$.bind($.touchLayer, 'enter-edit-reshape', function(){
    $('#jQUi').css('top', document.body.scrollTop+'px');
});
$.bind($.touchLayer, 'exit-edit-reshape', function(){
    $('#jQUi').css('top', 0);
});
```

Cheers! :)