# jqMobi: screen resizes when on-screen keyboard opens

Tags: iphone, ios, jqmobi, on-screen-keyboard

Trying to debug a jqMobi app in a Safari browser on an iPhone 4 (IOS6).

When I touch in a text input field, the on-screen keyboard appears, and the screen behind it zooms in so that the text input field pretty much fills the screen. This is normal iPhone behaviour and not a problem.

However, when I hit the "return" or "done" button, the screen stays zoomed in, with apparently no way of getting it back to normal.

I understand from the answer to question [jqmobi. on ios (ipod) when input field focused content moves up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250620/jqmobi-on-ios-ipod-when-input-field-focused-content-moves-up) that I should be able to detect the event when the keyboard closes, but I don't know what to call to tell iPhone Safari to go back to its normal zoomed-to-100% state.

Update: I've found a workaround, which is to add a "maximum-scale=1" to the meta name=viewport directive, but the trouble with that is that you now can't do any of the usual screen resizing manually.

Comment: I'm the lead of jqMobi - care to share a link and I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: Wow - I'm impressed that you're listening! Try test.bachtrack.com/test.html and test.bachtrack.com/nomax.html. In the first, the max-scale is set to 1, so you can't use the shrink and expand features. In the second, it isn't, displaying the problem that when you type something into the field, you can't get back to the normal size.  Sorry for the delay - it took a while to get the trivial example going.

Comment: No problem - this was a problem with the 1.0x branch.  If you use 1.1 or 1.2 from http://www.github.com/appmobi/jq.mobi it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of Ian (see the comment above) - yes, this is fixed in the 1.2 branch - it becomes possible to squeeze the screen back down to its normal scale.

I have other problems caused by the upgrade to 1.2, though: there's an issue with binding a click function; the function is being called with the whole window as a parameter rather than the item that is clicked (or touched) on. I'll just have to figure this one out and fix it separately.

Comment: Fix is already in github for 1.2 for the event scope issue.  Thanks for reporting the bug.